# Always on top, desktop YouTube player

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, youtube, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make a borderless, always on top, YouTube player, I've got almost everything set, here's my code:

```
    Dim html_aux As String = InputBox("Inserte URL YouTube")
    Dim s As String() = html_aux.Split("=")
    Dim htmlContent As String = "<html><body><iframe width='480'; height='271'; src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" & s(1) & "'; frameborder='0';></iframe></body></html>"
    Dim archivo As New System.IO.StreamWriter(".\Index.html", False)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(".\Index.html") Then
        archivo.WriteLine(htmlContent)
        archivo.Close()
    Else
        MkDir(".\Index.html")
        archivo.WriteLine(htmlContent)
        archivo.Close()
    End If
    Navegador.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\index.html"))
```

The problem comes when I launch the application; I get three errors coming from the WebBrowser control.

Script Error.

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'create'.

My guess is these errors come from WebBrowser not supporting the actual html code that `youtube.com/embed/url`  holds.

Is there a way to make WebBrowser deal with these conflicts? Should I stop trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the question, adding the following header to the HTML code solves the problem:

```
<html>
  <head> 
     <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' /> 
     ... headers code
  </head>
  <body>
     ... body code
  </body>
</html>
```

I no longer get script errors.

Whole code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub URLToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles URLToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim html_aux As String = InputBox("Inserte URL YouTube")
    Dim s As String() = html_aux.Split("=")
    Dim htmlContent As String =
        "<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
        </head>
        <body>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN' 'http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd'>
        <iframe width='480'; height='271'; src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" & s(1) & "'; frameborder='0';>
        </iframe>
        </body>
        </html>"
    Dim htmlFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter(".\Index.html", False)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(".\index.html") Then
        htmlFile.WriteLine(htmlContent)
        htmlFile.Close()
    Else
        MkDir(".\index.html")
        htmlFile.WriteLine(htmlContent)
        htmlFile.Close()
    End If
    Navegador.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\index.html"))
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.TopMost = True
End Sub

End Class
```